# CloudKit not storing string longer than 5096 chars

Tags: string, cloudkit, string-length

I am trying to manually store a **content** string using the CloudKit web interface and it is not accepting anything longer than 5096 chars.

Is there a way to overcome this and store strings of any length?

[image]

Comment: Simple, you use Assets

Comment: Thanks mate, will try that.